# Not able to create new project with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Nodejs version installed-8.12.0
npm version installed- 6.4.1

I was able to install angular CLI using "npm install -g @angular/cli"
but when I try to create a project using "ng new myapp", I get the error below:

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> Error: spawn
>   C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;E:\apache—maven-3.5.4\bin; ENOENT
>   at Process.ChildProcess._handle_onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
>   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick_js:139:11)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick_js:181:9)

Comment: Note: you can paste your error log directly in your question

Comment: Can you post the details around the Angular CLI version you have installed? You can see this via `ng v` in a command line

Comment: wondering what Maven does here... can you post the content of your PATH environment variable?

Comment: apache maven looks pretty weird.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel  Angular CLI verison is :  7.0.0-beta.4

Comment: @YoukouleleY PATH Environment Variable : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: @user3763246 it looks fine. Can you post your ComSpec environment variable?

Comment: @YoukouleleY ComSpec Environment Variable: %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;E:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and add the ComSpec variable because it's the key to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ComSpec environment variable is wrong, replace:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;E:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;
```

With the following:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
```

Then restart your `cmd` and retry to generate a project.

I have no idea why Maven got in there, it should not affect your Maven builds though.

Comment: This solution worked for me in creating/setting up my React Native project on my local system.

Answer (score 0):

These types of issues can happen due to proxy errors, typically behind a firewall.
See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11386

Do you have a mechanism to enter your proxy when running "npm install"?

Do note that in most instances where the process fails when installing the dependencies one can run "npm install" after the CLI finished configuring the new application.

Comment: I tried npm install after it failed to create project. But getting similar kind of error  npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;E:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;E:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;E:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;
npm ERR! circular-json@0.5.7 postinstall: `echo ''; echo 
cessor."; echo ''`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;E:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the circular-json@0.5.7 postinstall script.